# Counting the number of characters in multi - word vector R

Tags: r

I am attempting to solve problem 17 on [project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=17). The aim is to list all numbers from 1 to 1000 and count how many letters there are (excluding empty spaces and hyphens). Rather than doing it via base functions, I am using `stringr` and `english` libraries. However, my answer is a few thousands short. Here is my code:

```
library(english)
library(stringr)
words <- as.character(as.english(c(1:1000))) # transforming numbers to letters
words2 <- str_remove_all(words," ") # removing emtry spaces
words2 <- str_remove_all(words2,"-") # removing hyphens
length(as.vector(unlist(strsplit(words2,"")))) # finding the number of letters there is
```

The return from this code is 18451. I can do this problem via base R but I am interested in what I have done wrong here. The aim is to get the correct answer (see below) via using 2 libraries mentioned above. Correct answer:

> > 21124

Comment: what is your expected

Comment: @akrun The correct answer is hidden and is revealed when you put mouse on top of it.

Comment: I get `18451` `nchar(str_c(str_remove_all(words, "[- ]"), collapse=""))#
[1] 18451`

Comment: Yes but this answer is incorrect. The correct answer (the true answer) is different.

Comment: coulld be that the english is returning some words with less number of characters.  Or the correct answer may count the space as well

Comment: Or the use of `and` etc  is out of place i.e. in english, it would be `english(999)#
[1] nine hundred ninety-nine` but they expect some and in between

Comment: @akrun you are right. Some words have no "and" word. Cheers!

Comment: Is 21124 correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the words returned by `english` by default (USA style) doesn't include some words like 'and'

```
library(english)
library(stringr)
english(342)
#[1] three hundred forty-two

english(342, USA = TRUE)
#[1] three hundred forty-two
```

while the problem states.

```
342 (three hundred and forty-two)
```

which is in compliance with the British style.

Now if we change the default from USA to UK

```
english(342, UK = TRUE)
#[1] three hundred and forty-two
```

---

Using the British style

```
nchar(str_c(str_remove_all(english(1:1000, UK = TRUE), "[- ]"), collapse=""))
#[1] 21124
```